# Añadir parámetros de php a un enlace

Tags: php, post, parametros, href

Quiero añadir una variable que tengo en php como parámetro de una url en html.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Formulario y link ocultos, para ir a la pagina de detalle -->
<a id="link_detalle" href=<?php echo "detalle_pueblo?idPueblo=$idPueblo" ?> hidden></a> <!-- link oculto -->
        <form id="myForm_id" role="form" method="post" hidden>
            <input type="hidden" id="idPueblo" name="idPueblo" />
            <input id="sbmt_select_pueblo" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="submitbtn_select_pueblo" hidden>
        </form> <!-- formulario oculto -->

        <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submitbtn_select_pueblo'])) {
            $idPueblo = $_POST['idPueblo'];
            $_SESSION["id_pueblo"] = $_POST['idPueblo'];
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('link_detalle').click();</script>";
        }
        ?>
```

y más arriba lo siguiente:

```
// funcion para capturar el click en la tabla y enviar el formulario oculto que nos lleva a los detalles
        function seleccionarPueblo(clickedRow) {
                sessionStorage.setItem("busqueda_session", JSON.stringify(visibles)); // guardamos el conjunto de registros que se estaban mostrando en la sesion
                var myhidden = document.getElementById("idPueblo");
                var content_td = document.getElementById("td_" + (clickedRow.rowIndex - 1)).innerText;
                myhidden.value = content_td;
                document.getElementById("sbmt_select_pueblo").click();
            }
```

Simplemente quiero agregar la variable $idPueblo que guardo en el if a la url del enlace "link_detalle" como parámetro. Tal como está ahora es como si no es añadiese nada.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si cambias la posición del enlace y lo pones dentro del if con un echo?  Así obtendra la variable correctamente y luego le puedes pasar ese evento click en el siguiente echo

Comment: O bien cambias la posición del if y lo pones antes de cualquier salida, arriba del todo de tu script seguramente, y en lugar de combinar html + js + php lo haces todo desde php usando la funcion `header('location')`

Comment: Programar mezclando PHP y Javascript no tiene sentido hoy día. Ya existe Ajax y la nueva API Fetch, que sirven para mantener cada cosa en su lado, y las herramientas antes mencionadas sirven de pasarela entre cliente y servidor. Esto evita por un lado tener que recargar la página cada vez, e interactuar de una forma limpia entre cliente y servidor. Hoy día ya no se programa del modo en que lo haces aquí, considera por tanto incorporar Ajax o Fetch en este código.

Comment: Si mucho me apuras diria que no le hace falta ni el php para eso, diria que lo puede hacer todo en javascript dentro de la función seleccionarPueblo() sin tener que recargar la página para luego ser redireccionado de nuevo (a menos que quiera pasar por php para guardar algun dato en BD)

Comment: @masterguru He probado a meter el enlace dentro del if con ekko **            echo '<a id="link_detalle" href="detalle_pueblo?idPueblo=$idPueblo"  hidden></a>'; //<!-- link oculto -->
** y al avanzar a la isguiente página en la url tengo lo siguiente: **https:// memoriahistoricavalladolid.org/detalle_pueblo/?idPueblo=%24idPueblo** Ese 24 no entiendo de dónde sale ya que ya he comprobado que el id del pueblo es el correcto según qué pueblo escoja.

Comment: @A.Cedano La web no la he programado yo, solo me están pidiendo solucionar algunos problemas que tiene. No conocía nada de PHP hasta hace 1 semana y por supuesto no manejo Ajax ni nada del estilo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo conseguí arreglar. No es lo más elegante pero como solución temporal sirve

Dentro del if he introducido el enlace así:

```
echo '<a id=link_detalle href= detalle_pueblo?idPueblo='.$idPueblo  .' hidden></a>'; //<!-- link oculto -->
```

Y bueno en la otra página cojo la información:

```
$idPueblo = $_GET["idPueblo"];
```

No recordaba que para concatenar se utilizaba el . delante... Llevo solo 1 semana lo siento ^^.

Comment: bien! me alegro que lo hayas solucionado :-)  Y no te disculpes, aqui venimos todos a aprender, y aunque lleves años y años siempre se aprende algo más cada dia (eso si eres curioso, claro)